# Javascript: How to call <li> element value

Tags: javascript

can anyone give me the javascipt code to extract following instances of `sf_number` from my HTML?

```
<ul class="multi_value_field" style="width: 99.5%;">
<li class="choice" choice_id="sf_number">sf_number<a class="close">×</a><input type="hidden" name="ticket[set_tags][]" value="sf_number" style="display: none;"></li>
<li class="search_field_item"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="20"></li>
</ul>
```

Basically I want to replace all three instances of `sf_number` with a different
value from another field. This is the code I have made to try and extract sf_number but doesn't work so far:

```
var n2 = document.getElementsByClassName("multi_value_field").getElementsByClassName("choice");
```

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
How can I change my existing code by using your suggestions below?

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
copy = function()
{
    var n1 = document.getElementById("ticket_fields_20323656");
    var n2 = document.getElementById("choice").getElementsByClassName("sf_number")[0] ;
    n2.value = n1.value;
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="copy" onClick="copy();" />
</html>​​​​​
```

**Update**

This doesn't seem to work, is it correct?

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
copy = function()
{
var fields = document.getElementsByClassName("multi_value_field")[0].getElementsByClassName("choice");

for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)

    fields[i].setAttribute("choice_id", "document.getElementById("ticket_fields_20323656").value");
    fields[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = "document.getElementById("ticket_fields_20323656").value";
    fields[i].firstChild.nodeValue = "document.getElementById("ticket_fields_20323656").value";
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="copy" onClick="copy();" />
</html>​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

There is no HTML attribute named "choice_id", and using non–standard attributes is not a good idea. If you want to identify a number of elements using the value 'sf_number', you should use a class instead, e.g.

```
<li class="choice sf_number">sf_number<a class="close">×</a>...</li>
```

Now you can get all elements with class of "sf_number" using `getElementsByClassName`, or `querySelectorAll`. You can add a shim for one or both of those to make life easier, then use:

```
var sfNumbers = document.querySelectorAll('.sf_number');
```

Then you can iterate over the collection per other answers.

An element can have multiple classes, the above will select only those with a class of 'sf_number'. If you want to select the text `sf_number`, you are much better off putting it in a span or similar element so you can reference it more directly. Relying on different browsers to insert text nodes consistently is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

`var n2 = document.getElementsByClassName("multi_value_field")`  returns a node List

So you need to use a for loop to iterate the list..

```
var n2 = document.getElementsByClassName("multi_value_field");

for(var i =0;i< n2.length;i++){
  var $li =  n2[i].getElementsByClassName("choice"); This is again a Node list.

  for(var j = 0;j< $li.length ; j++){
     $li[j] // This the li in question
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
var n1 = document.getElementById("ticket_fields_20323656"); 
var n2 = document.getElementById("choice").getElementsByClassName("sf_number");
// The above line again return's node List .... 
n2.value = n1.value;
```

Replace that by this line with this if you feel it has a single class

```
var n2 = document.getElementById("choice").getElementsByClassName("sf_number")[0] ;
```

But the thing is I don't see the element with `id="choice"` in the `HTML.`

Comment: Thanks Sushanth, see above for my latest comment in response to David's answer, if you have any input it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Do you also want to replace the text?

```
<script>
var fields = document.getElementsByClassName("multi_value_field")[0].getElementsByClassName("choice");

for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
{
    fields[i].setAttribute("choice_id", "something else");
    fields[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = "something else";
    fields[i].firstChild.nodeValue = "something else";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hey David, thanks for that, yes I need to replace 'sf_number' with the value from 'ticket_fields_20323656' on page load, can you amend the below for me? var n1 already works for me:

<script type="text/javascript">
copy = function()
{
    var n1 = document.getElementById("ticket_fields_20323656");
    var n2 = document.getElementById("choice").getElementsByClassName("sf_number");
    n2.value = n1.value;
}
</script>

Comment: Much appreciated David, so if possible can you update my code above to your suggestion and I can see if it works for me?

Comment: well, just replace the string `"something else"` in my code by `document.getElementById("ticket_fields_20323656").value` and you should be done.